Error about the uaclient package when running update-manager
When trying to run update-manager, the following error is thrown:
$ update-manager 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/update-manager", line 38, in <module>
    from UpdateManager.UpdateManager import UpdateManager
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/UpdateManager.py", line 30, in <module>
    import uaclient.api.u.pro.packages.updates.v1 as ua
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'uaclient.api'


There are some answers to similar questions (e.g. here) that suggest to reinstall the opcua and opcua-client packages.
For me, the problem went away after completely uninstalling the opcua and opcua-client packages.
My impression is that there exist two packages with the same name uaclient, one inside the opcua ecosystem and the other inside the update-manager. Unfortunately, I can not investigate further at the moment.
